# How to abstract .map to other React Component for Listing api calls

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
garage = /api/call

<List>
    {garage.map((car: Car, idx: number) => (
    <TouchableOpacity
        key={idx} 
        onPress={() => doSomething(car.color)}
    >
        <Car name={car.name} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    ))}
</List>
```

I use the same list format `<List />` for others api calls I would to abstract also the .map, **but I need it individual list item data** to do some stuff!

Comment: what is the issue and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: looks very similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/69844607/12160508